# WebStorm Conditional Code Folding

Tags: webstorm

I'm wondering whether there is any conditional code folding mechanism in WebStorm. When writing Karma tests, I find that I have many nested `describe` blocks containing `beforeEach` and `it` functions.

Is there a way I can fold all `beforeEach` / `it` statements on any level but leave the `describe` blocks unfolded?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I never got a response unfortunately, this could be something posted on a JetBrains forum as a feature suggestion